# django запрос изображению

Tags: python, django

py есть такой метод

```
def image(request):
    path = request.POST.get('path' , '')
    image_data = open(BASE_DIR + "/" + path , 'rb').read()
    return HttpResponse(image_data , content_type='image/png')
```

Если использовать при запросе метод POST работает без проблем. Если использовать GET то получаю ошибку `[Errno 13] Permission denied: D:\\django\\project\\path`. Использую ОС Windows. Разрешение пользователем для всех папок поставил FullControll

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам необходимо использовать средства Джанго для получения изображений. Изображения - это статические файлы. Как это реализовать подробно описано в документации - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/